# Приведение типов

Tags: ооп, c++

Верно ли делать константное приведение ссылки?

```
void func( const ISomeAbsClass & param) {
    ISomeAbsClass someAbsClass = const_cast<ISomeAbsClass &>(param);
    ...
}
```

Comment: по-моему const здесь лишнее.

Answer (score 3):

Такое приведение как у вас не имеет смысла, т.к. после приведения все равно происходит вызов конструктора копирования, который обычно имеет вид A(const A& a).
Чтобы изменить объект на который ссылается param, надо сделать так:

```
ISomeAbsClass& someAbsClass = const_cast<ISomeAbsClass &>(param);
someAbsClass.someNonConstantMethod();
```

Стоит помнить, что почти всегда необходимость в const_cast возникает при плохом проектировании программы и его можно избежать.